# MVC3 dropdown list that displays mutliple properties per item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, properties, drop-down-menu, viewbag

I want to have a dropdownlist in my view that displays a patient's ID, First Name, and Last Name.  With the code below, it displays each patient's First Name.  How can I pass all three properties into the viewbag and have them display in the dropdownlist?

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
            {ViewBag.Patient_ID = new SelectList(db.Patients, "Patient_ID", "First_Name");
             return View();
            }
```

View

```
    <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("Patient_ID", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Patient_ID)
            </div>
```

Thanks.

Ok, I have edited my code as follows, and I receive the error "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'SelectedPatientId'."

```
Controller


    public ActionResult Create()
            {
                var model = new MyViewModel();

        {
             var Patients = db.Patients.ToList().Select(p => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = p.Patient_ID.ToString(),
                Text = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", p.Patient_ID, p.First_Name, p.Last_Name)
            });

            var Prescribers = db.Prescribers.ToList().Select(p => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = p.DEA_Number.ToString(),
        Text = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", p.DEA_Number, p.First_Name, p.Last_Name)
    });

            var Drugs = db.Drugs.ToList().Select(p => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = p.NDC.ToString(),
                Text = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", p.NDC, p.Name, p.Price)
            });


        };
                return View(model);
            }
```

> View Model

```
    public class MyViewModel
        {
            [Required]
            public int? SelectedPatientId { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Patients { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public int? SelectedPrescriber { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Prescribers { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public int? SelectedDrug { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Drugs { get; set; }
        }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

     @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedPatientId,
        Model.Patients,
        "-- Select patient ---"
    )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedPatientId)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>

         @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedPrescriber,
        Model.Patients,
        "-- Select prescriber ---"
    )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedPrescriber)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Comment: That error usually means your item list is null

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you not to use any `ViewBag` at all and define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int? SelectedPatientId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Patients { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action fill and pass this view model to the view:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Patients = db.Patients.ToList().Select(p => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = p.Patient_ID.ToString(),
            Text = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", p.Patient_ID, p.First_Name, p.Last_Name)
        });
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally in your strongly typed view display the dropdown list:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedPatientId, 
        Model.Patients, 
        "-- Select patient ---"
    )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedPatientId)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Comment: I don't believe I can use this approach.  In addition to the DropDownList containing the list of patient names, I also have other drop down lists containing data from other entities.  My Create View is strongly typed of Models.Rx.  An Rx contains relationships between Patient, Prescriber, and Drug.  If I follow your approach I won't be able to pull in anything not inside "MyViewModel", is that correct?

Comment: @DanielHendrix, in the updated example, you have properly added another field to hold the prescribers dropdown. And then in your create view you instantiate this view model (`var model = new MyViewModel()`), then you are querying your database or whatever and storing the results in some local variables such as Patients, Prescribers and Drugs but never set any of the properties of your view model. You need to set them `model.Patients = patients; ...` before returning to the view.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to accomplish that is just creating additional property on your model either by modifying model class or adding/modifying a partial class

```
[NotMapped]
public string DisplayFormat
{
    get
    {
      return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", Patient_ID, First_Name, Last_Name);
    }  
}
```

Comment: I recieve the following error when modifying the model.  I used the Database First approach.Error 1 Error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 561:No mapping specified for properties Patient.DisplayList in Set Patients.
An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
  Entity is type [CAHODModel.Patient]

Comment: right, you should prefix that parameter with [NotMapped] I've updated my sample. Please take a  look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958